# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined in passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

```
  app.get('/getUser', function(req, res) {

     console.log(req.user.username);

         res.json({'user':req.user.username}); 
    });
```

When I login to passportjs, this does not return any error, but when I am not logged in, it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` error, I need to send res.json only if it is defined,

```
     app.get('/getUser', function(req, res) {

         console.log(req.user.username);
    if(typeof req.user.username!="undefined")
             res.json({'user':req.user.username}); 
           else
     res.json({'user':"Anonymous"}); 
                    });
```

but it gives error for conditional statement, How do I error handle it?

Comment: if(typeof req.user !="undefined")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport places user on the req object.  If you have not performed authentication with Passport, there will be no user object on the request object.  Therefore, req.user will be undefined.  As you can probably imagine, undefined does not have a property named username, causing your error.

You probably want something like:

```
username = req.user ? req.user.username : "Anonymous"
res.json({'user':username});
```